How to get the namespace exports from .onLoad()?
getNamespaceExports() returns an empty vector there, can I access or rebuild this info by other means ?
semi-reprex, in any package with exported objects :
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
   print(getNamespaceExports(pkgname))
}


We can trigger a custom function that executes after the package loading is completed.
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  setHook(
    packageEvent(pkgname, "onLoad"),
    function(...) {
      exports <- getNamespaceExports(pkgname)
      # Your code here
    }, 
    action = "append"
  )
}


Are you intentionally masking the base .onLoad ?

There is no base::.onLoad, it's a function that has to be created and is then recognised

Thanks- tho' I must say the ns-hooks man page is misleading, since it allows ?.onLoad to be accepted as existing in the sense that it'll pull up the man page which lists it as a function.

I agree, the doc on any sort of hooks in R is generally more obscure than it could be
